# Unix printer output to a file

Tags: unix, printers

I am using this code in Putty on Win7 to print my file on Linux.

```
lp -d myPrinter myfile.out
```

There is no problem with this code, it works perfectly. But I am having some Turkish character problem. So everytimeIi change something, I run this code to see if it changes. So it make wasting of paper.Now, this is my question;

Is there a way to print a file on a virtual printer and to see result in a file, like microsoft XPS document writer and *.xps file. If there is, where will be the result file.

I am new at Unix, please forgive me, thanks.

Comment: The `cat myfile.out` command will print the file to your terminal window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution,
First install Cups-PDF to your unix server.Then run this code:

```
lp -d Cups-PDF myfile.out
```

Then go to ${HOME}/Desktop folder to see the result.Probably your pdf name will be myFile.pdf.To learn ${HOME}, just write ${HOME} to putty.